# How to customise Power BI ribbon for Modelling

Tags: powerbi

I would like to change the default summarization function in the Modelling tab of Power BI Desktop to view actual value instead of summation of data, as described in [this question](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/quot-Value-quot-field-defaulting-to-quot-Sum-quot-instead-of/td-p/125052).

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBf5rYR8KoM) on customising ribbon in Power BI:
[image]

which suggested checking `updated ribbon` option in `File/Options and settings/ Options/ Preview features`, but there was not this option on my Power BI desktop:

[image]

---

Question edit:

I would like to edit a Power BI app which had already been published, so I will have to edit in Workspace, where I notice the default summarization is retained. How can I remove the default summarization setting the  for Power BI app in Workspace?

Comment: Preview features do not always remain available. It looks like this one was not retained.

To clarify your question, why do you have to edit in Workspace? Is it not possible for you to edit the app and republish?

Answer (score -1):

(*Only for the first part of the question)

There seems to be a way to work around this with [YouTube - 35 Don't summarize option Power BI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0OJOBrQtSA).

Go to `Data` tab, click on the table on the right and edit `Summarization` option in the ribbon to `Don't summarize`.

Comment: The solution in that video no longer works because the "Default Summarization" option has been removed from the ribbon.